# Python: saving NEW excel with a splitted column

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

alright say I have an excel file that looks like this: http://oi44.tinypic.com/52e8fp.jpg

the fourth column (D) has several values in it. I want to use Python to create a new excel file, only with that column split into several. basically I want this: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2a7hlzb.jpg

I'm just not sure how I would go about creating "new" columns? I'll have to split column D, and then what? is there a way I could make lists with every value belonging to a different column (i.e. john, smith, 23, fireman, purple, cat) and then write those lists as a new excel file?

I'm using **xlrd** and **xlwt** to do this.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use **xlcopy** method form [**xlutils**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils) package. It can copy xlrd-opened XLS file to  xlwt-writable one.

```
input_file = xlrd.open_workbook(input_name, formatting_info=True)
output_file = xlutils.copy(input_file)
```

**output_file** can be then manipulated by standard **xlwt** methods.